# Link to a file in a higher level folder

Tags: html, file, href

I'm having troubles serving a document which is in a higher level than my root folder.

```
<a href='../../home/folder/document.docx'>Proposal</a>
```

In the browser the above gets interpreted as:

```
http://localhost/home/folder/document.docx
```

I cannot see the browser going up in the folders and then the answer I get is:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /home/folder/document.docx was not found on this server.
```

I have tried in Firefox and Chrome, it happens the same. I am using Apache Web Server on a Linux machine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is strange because if the file is the root folder it works: <a href='root/document.docx'> opens the save as modal window. This is what I want but going to a upper level folder.

Comment: The above could be happening because you're on localhost.

Comment: It also works when I am not on localhost. That's why I thought it will work to serve a file located in another folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not redirect your visitors to a file outside of your document root (where you have your index.html).
People can't see files higher than where `http://localhost/` ends up in.

A solution would be to put that `.docx` inside of your document root (where your index.html is in).

You can however let PHP serve the file using the [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function.
But don't forget that www-data would need to have access to the file you're serving.

Comment: fair enough, I didn't know that. But I think my client will want that folder structure outside the document root.

Comment: Well there is a way to pull it off. You can get a php script to serve the document.docx. http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: The thing is that I am serving this file from JavaScript.

Comment: That's alright, you can point your javascript to i.e.: "download.php?file=document.docx", then the PHP file can serve the document.docx. Be aware of the fact that the above is very unsafe!

Comment: How the above could be unsafe?

Comment: Well people could change that url so that it serves them a file filled with passwords or something. They can pretty much download anything from your filesystem where www-data has permission to. It's best to use predefined words or ids like this: `download.php?file=23`.